# How to make multiple (more than 2) dependent Dropdowns in python

Tags: python, tkinter, dropdown

I have this case. There are 3 dropdown lists A,B,C. List A is independent. List B depends on value select in List A. List C depends on value selected in List B. Is it possible to make in Python/ Tkinter. I have successfully made the first part i-e List B becomes dependent on List A value. But when I use the selected value of List B to generate value of List C, List C shows blank values.
Please help! Here is my code.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter  # <- import the CustomTkinter module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from openpyxl import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Initializations
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Light")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

root_tk = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window (you can also use normal tkinter.Tk window)
root_tk.geometry("1030x620")
root_tk.title("CustomTkinter Test")

# region Configure Custome Style of Combobox and Entry Widgets
style= ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure("TCombobox", foreground="#1e1e1e",arrowcolor="#1e1e1e")
style.map("TCombobox",fieldbackground=[("disabled", "1e1e1e")])
style.map("TEntry",fieldbackground=[("disabled", "1e1e1e")])
# endregion


# Appearances
# Text colors for labels
nlcolor = "#1e1e1e"                     # -------- Normal Label Text Color
hdcolor = "#EB3F3F"                     # -------- Headings Background Color


# Binder Functions
def bind_mkmodel(e):
    if mkmodel.get()=="3051CD":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class1)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get()=="3051SCD":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class2)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get()=="3051SMV--1or 2":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class3)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get() == "3051SMV--3 or 4":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class4)
        modclass.current(0)
    else:
        modclass.config(values=[""])
        modclass.current(0)
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
def bind_modclass(e):
    if modclass.get()=="Std":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp1)
        dp.current(0)
    elif modclass.get()=="S_Ultra" or modclass.get() == "S_Classic":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp2)
        dp.current(0)
    elif modclass.get() == "S_Ultra for Flow":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp3)
        dp.current(0)
    elif modclass.get() == "SMV12_Classic" or modclass.get() == "SMV34_Ultra" or modclass.get() == "SMV34_Classic":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp4)
        dp.current(0)
    elif modclass.get() == "SMV12_Ultra for Flow":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp5)
        dp.current(0)
    elif modclass.get() == "SMV34_Ultra for Flow":
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        dp.config(values=list_dp6)
        dp.current(0)
    else:
        dp.config(values=[""])
        dp.current(0)
        dp.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

# region Frames definition
frame_0 = Frame(root_tk,background="white")
frame_0.place(x=0,y=0,height=1100,width=150)

frame_6 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="white")
frame_6.place(x=10,y=10)
# endregion
# --------- FRAME 6 COMPONENTS ---------
# Labels Creation
lab_heading6 = Label(frame_6, text="  Dropdowns",anchor=W,width=35,font='Arial 10 bold',bg=hdcolor,fg="white")
lab_mkmodel = Label(frame_6, text="  List A",anchor=W,width=23,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="white",fg=nlcolor)
lab_modclass = Label(frame_6, text="  List B",anchor=W,width=23,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="white",fg=nlcolor)
lab_dp = Label(frame_6, text="  List C",anchor=W,width=23,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="white",fg=nlcolor)
# Labels positioning
lab_heading6.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=10,columnspan=2)
lab_mkmodel.grid(row=1, column=0)
lab_modclass.grid(row=2, column=0)
lab_dp.grid(row=3, column=0)
# Creating List A dropdown
list_mkmodel = ["3051CD", "3051SCD", "3051SMV--1or 2","3051SMV--3 or 4","Custom"]
mkmodel = ttk.Combobox(frame_6,values=list_mkmodel,width=13,style="TCombobox")
mkmodel.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx="11")
mkmodel.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",bind_mkmodel)
# Creating List B dropdown
list_class1 = ["Std"]
list_class2 = ["S_Ultra", "S_Classic","S_Ultra for Flow"]
list_class3 = ["SMV12_Classic", "SMV12_Ultra for Flow"]
list_class4 = ["SMV34_Ultra","SMV34_Classic", "SMV34_Ultra for Flow"]
modclass = ttk.Combobox(frame_6,values=[""],width=13,style="TCombobox")
modclass.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx="11")
modclass.current(0)
modclass.event_generate("<<ComboboxSelected>>")

modclass.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",bind_modclass)
# Creating List C dropdown
list_dp1 = ["1,2,3,4,5"]
list_dp2 = ["1A,2A,3A,4A,5A"]
list_dp3 = ["2A,3A"]
list_dp4 = ["1,2,2 SP=5,3,3 SP=5,4,5"]
list_dp5 = ["2,2 SP=5,3,3 SP=5,4"]
list_dp6 = ["2,2 SP=5,3,3 SP=5"]
dp = ttk.Combobox(frame_6,values=[""],width=13,style="TCombobox")
dp.current(0)
dp.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx="11")

root_tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Everything works on my Windows 10 computer, list C changes values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've been told in the comment, your code is working and list C content does change.
If you want to automate the first selection of C then you are probably looking for the event_generate method that should come right after the setting of current(0):

```
def bind_mkmodel(e):
    if mkmodel.get() == "3051CD":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class1)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get() == "3051SCD":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class2)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get() == "3051SMV--1or 2":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class3)
        modclass.current(0)
    elif mkmodel.get() == "3051SMV--3 or 4":
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        modclass.config(values=list_class4)
        modclass.current(0)
    else:
        modclass.config(values=[""])
        modclass.current(0)
        modclass.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    modclass.event_generate("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
```

Comment: Thank you so much that solves my problem.

Comment: He Zeev , I have tried your suggested modification to generate first seletion of List C automatically. But it doesnt do so. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: modclass.event_generate("<<ComboboxSelected>>") is generating select event for the modclass Combobox. It is like you click on the current choice.
I'm not sure what you have done, If you can update your code in the question, I can take a look at the code.

Comment: Ok I have updated the code. Can you please check now. Its not generating the first value of ListC automatically. e.g When I select 3051CD in List 1 it shows Std in List2, but List C automatically doesnt show the first value and I have to click List C drop down to see the values.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear. The generating of selection should happen in the bind_mkmodel function. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wow it works like a dream. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks mate. Can u share some light on how this event_generate is functioning right here so in future I can get the idea for the proper use of it

Comment: When we bind an event to an element: modclass.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",bind_modclass), it is like you asking the element to trigger the function when the event that was requested has been applied to this element. Selecting from the mkmodel Combobox is calling the bind_mkmodel function, and inside the function, we set modclass with the relevant list, and select the first item in the list: modclass.current(0). So when we generating the <<ComboboxSelected>> event it is triggering the event that we bind.